# Authorize.NET create customer profile with test.authorize.net?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, authorize.net

In authorize.net, is it possible to create a customer profile + customer payment profile with the https://test.authorize.net/gateway/transact.dll page (test mode)?
I need to return the customer profileid and paymentprofileid(s) to make offline payments.

I could do this with the API (C#) after creating a customer profile with customer payment profile and calling [charge customer profile](http://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/index.html#payment-transactions-charge-a-customer-profile). But I don't want the user to enter card details in my website, need to do it with a Authorize.NET UI and get the response.

Is this possible to do?

Comment: Updated documentation for creating customer profiles: https://developer.authorize.net/api/reference/features/customer_profiles.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it's possible to do token API credit card transactions with Authorize.NET.
Details can be found [in this CIM guide](http://www.authorize.net/content/dam/authorize/documents/CIM_XML_guide.pdf) document (chapter 4).

- Step 1 - Create a customer profile with the API. (just basic customer
  details)
- Step 2 - Get the token* for the profile
  (getHostedProfilePageRequest). This is where I got stuck, "mystery
  API call", I am sharing the code below.
- Step 3 - Create a form as
  below and make a post. (this will direct the customer to a hosted
  form to add/edit payment methods or shipping addresses)
- Step 4 - Try
  to query customer payment profiles for the customer, you will find
  the added payment profile.

Format of the form,

```
    <form method="post" action="https://test.authorize.net/
     profile/manage">
      <input type="hidden" name="token"
         value="pfGaUNntoTxZYeqqYDjGCQ4qyCHcsXGXLJ2i7MPCEiH6CH5n5qKqcl8EB
            iTClxu01BSeH5eZg7LVUVVzw5kJKVMitQ3pyMB5UZCduMWd6Ku9aT2gyFm69EKMG
            fyWPmI4p+Bb4XXXXXXXXXXXXWlM6f2xd7aRu1XBn0WXoPxK1j9FMGX2CNCoCB
            p3cOXB7"/>
      <input type="submit" value="Manage payment and shipping
      information"/>
     </form>
```

Here is the code I found for the mystery API call to "getHostedProfilePageRequest" which was not available in the C# SDK in [Github](https://github.com/AuthorizeNet/sample-code-csharp). It's available in the soap client, but this code simply send the XML request over http (sounds pretty similar to web service).

```
public static string GetHostedSessionKey(UInt32 customerProfileID, Uri callingPage)
    {
        try
        {
            //build a path to IframeCommunicator from the calling page
            string communicatorPath = String.Format("{0}://{1}:{2}", callingPage.Scheme, callingPage.Host, callingPage.Port);
            string[] segments = callingPage.Segments;
            //replace the very last entry with contentx/IframeCommunicator.html
            segments[segments.GetUpperBound(0)] = "/contentx/IframeCommunicator.html";
            foreach (string s in segments)
                communicatorPath += s;

            string requestXML = String.Format("<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>" +
                                                "<getHostedProfilePageRequest xmlns=\"AnetApi/xml/v1/schema/AnetApiSchema.xsd\">" +
                                                    "<merchantAuthentication>" +
                                                        "<name>{0}</name>" +
                                                        "<transactionKey>{1}</transactionKey>" +
                                                    "</merchantAuthentication>" +
                                                    "<customerProfileId>{2}</customerProfileId>" +
                                                    "<hostedProfileSettings>" +
                                                        "<setting>" +
                                                            "<settingName>hostedProfilePageBorderVisible</settingName>" +
                                                            "<settingValue>false</settingValue>" +
                                                        "</setting>" +
                                                        "<setting>" +
                                                            "<settingName>hostedProfileIFrameCommunicatorUrl</settingName>" +
                                                            "<settingValue>{3}</settingValue>" +
                                                        "</setting>" +
                                                    "</hostedProfileSettings>" +
                                                "</getHostedProfilePageRequest>",
                                            {your merchant login ID},
                                            {your merchant transaction key},
                                            customerProfileID,
                                            communicatorPath);
         string XMLURL = "https://apitest.authorize.net/xml/v1/request.api";
            System.Net.HttpWebRequest req = (System.Net.HttpWebRequest)System.Net.HttpWebRequest.Create(XMLURL);
            req.CachePolicy = new System.Net.Cache.RequestCachePolicy(System.Net.Cache.RequestCacheLevel.NoCacheNoStore);
            req.KeepAlive = false;
            req.Timeout = 30000; //30 seconds
            req.Method = "POST";
            byte[] byte1 = null;
            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding encoding = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();
            byte1 = encoding.GetBytes(requestXML);
            req.ContentType = "text/xml";
            req.ContentLength = byte1.Length;
            System.IO.Stream reqStream = req.GetRequestStream();
            reqStream.Write(byte1, 0, byte1.Length);
            reqStream.Close();

            System.Net.WebResponse resp = req.GetResponse();
            System.IO.Stream read = resp.GetResponseStream();
            System.IO.StreamReader io = new System.IO.StreamReader(read, new         System.Text.ASCIIEncoding());
            string data = io.ReadToEnd();
            resp.Close();

            //parse out value
            XmlDocument doc = new XmlDocument();
            doc.LoadXml(data);
            XmlNodeList token = doc.GetElementsByTagName("token");
            return token[0].InnerText;
        }
        catch (System.Exception ex)
        {
            Utility.NotifyOnException(ex, String.Format("profID={0}", customerProfileID));
            return null;
        }
    }
```

Found this code [here](http://community.developer.authorize.net/t5/Integration-and-Testing/How-to-call-GetHostedProfilePage/td-p/14208)